# Android Compose Material3 Layout with TopAppBar, TabRow and Tabs, ModalNavigationDrawer and SearchBar

Tags: tabs, android-jetpack-compose, searchbar, drawer, appbar

I am creating a Android Compose Material 3 layout with `TopAppBar`, `TabRow` with multiple `Tab`s, `ModalNavigationDrawer` and a `SearchBar`.  Here is my code:

```
@Composable
fun MyBar(drawerState: DrawerState, scope: CoroutineScope
) {
    var title = "MyBar"
    var state by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val tabs = listOf("Home", "Settings", "Profile")
    var mystate = remember {
        mutableStateOf(true)
    }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        if(mystate.value) {
        MyTopAppBar(mystate = mystate)}
        else{
            MySearchBar(mystate)
        }
        if(mystate.value) {
            Row() {
                Box(modifier = Modifier.size(54.dp)) {
                    IconButton(
                        onClick = {
                            if (drawerState.isClosed) scope.launch { drawerState.open() }
                            else scope.launch { drawerState.close() }
                        }
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Filled.Menu,
                            contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.more_options_button),
                            tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant,
                            modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)
                        )
                    }
                }
                TabRow(
                    selectedTabIndex = state,
                ) {
                    tabs.forEachIndexed { index, tabTitle ->
                        Tab(
                            modifier = Modifier.height(36.dp),
                            selected = state == index,
                            onClick = { }
                        ) {
                            Text(text = tabTitle)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            MyDrawer(drawerState, scope)
        }
    }
}
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MyTopAppBar(mystate: MutableState<Boolean>){
    TopAppBar(
        scrollBehavior =
        TopAppBarDefaults.pinnedScrollBehavior(),
        title = { Text("MyTopBar") },
        navigationIcon = {
            if (true) {
                FilledIconButton(
                    onClick = { },
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                    colors = IconButtonDefaults.filledIconButtonColors(
                        containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface,
                        contentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface
                    )
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
                        contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.back_button),
                        modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        },
        actions = {
            IconButton(
                onClick = {mystate.value = false },
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.Search,
                    contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.more_options_button),
                    tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant,
                    modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)
                )
            }
            IconButton(
                onClick = { },
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.MoreVert,
                    contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.more_options_button),
                    tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant,
                    modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    )
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MyDrawer(drawerState: DrawerState, scope: CoroutineScope){

 //   val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Closed)
//    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
// icons to mimic drawer destinations
    val items = listOf(Icons.Default.Favorite, Icons.Default.Face, Icons.Default.Email)
    val selectedItem = remember { mutableStateOf(items[0]) }
    var mydrawerState = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    ModalNavigationDrawer(
        drawerState = drawerState,
        drawerContent = {
            ModalDrawerSheet(
            ) {
                Spacer(Modifier.height(12.dp))
                items.forEach { item ->
                    NavigationDrawerItem(
                        icon = { Icon(item, contentDescription = null) },
                        label = { Text(item.name) },
                        selected = item == selectedItem.value,
                        onClick = {
                            scope.launch { drawerState.close() }

                            selectedItem.value = item
                        },
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(NavigationDrawerItemDefaults.ItemPadding)
                    )
                }
            }
        },
        content = {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Text(text = "Text in Drawer content 1",)
                Text(text = "Text in Drawer content 2",)
            }
        }
    )
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MySearchBar( mystate: MutableState<Boolean>
) {

    var text by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    var active by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

    SearchBar(
 //       modifier = Modifier.height(64.dp),
        query = "search text",
        onQueryChange = {},
        onSearch = {},
        active = true,
        onActiveChange = {},
        leadingIcon = {
            FilledIconButton(
                onClick = { mystate.value = true },
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                colors = IconButtonDefaults.filledIconButtonColors(
                    containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface,
                    contentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface
                )
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
                    contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.back_button),
                    modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)
                )
            }
        },
        trailingIcon = {Icon(Icons.Default.Search, contentDescription = null) }
    ) {
        Text(text = "Text in Search content 1",)
        Text(text = "Text in Search content 2",)
    }
}
```

The above composable is called from `MainActivity` like so:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            MYTest3Theme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Closed)
                    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
                    Scaffold(
                        modifier = Modifier,

                        { MyBar(drawerState = drawerState, scope = scope )},

                        content = {
                            Column{
                                Text("Text from Acaffold content 1")
                                Text("Text from Acaffold content 2")
                                Text("Text from Acaffold content 3")
                                Text("Text from Acaffold content 4")
                                Text("Text from Acaffold content 5")
                                Text("Text from Acaffold content 6")
                                Text("Text from Acaffold content 7")
                                Text("Text from Acaffold content 8")

                          }


                        })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here the TabRow with Tabs is placed below the TopAppBar.  There is a button on the left of the TabRow, which when clicked opens the ModalNavigationDrawer.  When the search icon is clicked the searchbar becomes visible and all other components are hidden.

All of the above functionality works fine.  But I have the following issues:

1. Are the components in the layout properly set, or is there a better way to organize them.
2. The query text in SearchBar is not aligned with the Title of TopAppBar.  This is perhaps because the natural height of TopAppBar is different from SearchBar.  How can I align the two.  When I reduce the height of the SearchBar to match that of TopAppBar,  the bottom part of the query text in the search box is being truncated.
3. I intent to put my data in the content parameter of the Scaffold.  How can I make the text here start from the bottom of the TabRow, and when in search mode it should start from the bottom of the SearchBar.

Thanks